# Bug in ExtJS 6 Admin Dashboard Menu

Tags: javascript, extjs

I came across one nasty bug in [Admin Dashboard](http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/examples/admin-dashboard/#dashboard) example. The problem is that on small sized screens and with a larger number of menu items, there is no vertical scroller. So, when you load your page for the first time, it is possible that you will not see some menu items which are close to the bottom. Here is a screen shot that demonstrates this critical issue:

[image]

I use this menu as a template in my own application and see this bug. I tried to set `scrollable:true` on the west region and on the `treelist` itself, but to no avail. So, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the `scrollable` config on the `treelist` will not work, because it doesn't inherit from `Ext.Component`, the class that introduces this config. But you can get along with this by setting `overflow: auto;` (that's what basically scrollable does) on the `treelist` like so:

```
    xtype: 'treelist',
    style: 'overflow: auto;'
```

Or, of course, by applying a class that has this property.

Comment: Thank you, sir! I will check it in a minute!